# Action for delete some posts jomsocial

Tags: joomla2.5, jomsocial

I'm building a website using `Joomla 2.5`, `JReviews` and `Jomsocial 2.6.2`.
Here is my big problem:

`userA` is friends with `userB` and `userA` decides to post something to `userB's` wall. The big problem is that `userB` can't delete that (and it's a very big problem if is something nasty).
I tried to change and adapt some code but with no solution. You can see this on `Jomsocial` demo: [Jomsocial demo](http://demo.jomsocial.com)

I think these files control the deleting and hiding activities. 
You can find them here: 
[Activity 1](http://speedy.sh/n8FAr/activities.apps.php)

[Activity 2](http://speedy.sh/NqpK3/activities.index.php)

[Activity 3](http://speedy.sh/kFZVD/activities.php)

It would help a lot if someone has experience with `Jomsocial` and knows how to resolve this issue.